updating QGIS: I can´t update Keyring
Add the QGIS repo for the latest stable QGIS (3.36.x Maidenhead) to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources:
a: What exactly is a repository (what does it look like?) and how to add? what do they mean? answered
b: I see Keyrings that where 'modified' before they where 'created' by 2 years..?? answered
c: I can not find the latest download of said keyring,(meaning today's) I have keyrings in different files. they all have different modified dates. I allso have an trusted file or map: /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg
I ruled out the root-probl, at least I thought, root is only snapstore?
Anybody enlighten me please. Thank you in advance. Vincent

Iḿ sorry if i did something wrong. I tried to figure out your suggestions and adding a comment or response. Im new to this. I really dont know what im doing wrong.

There are several steps to install QGis, none are difficult but you do have to follow all of them in order.
First install the needed software tools:
sudo apt install gnupg software-properties-common

Then you need to add the signing key:
sudo mkdir -m755 -p /etc/apt/keyrings  
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg https://download.qgis.org/downloads/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg

The first line creates the keyring directory if it doesn't exist and then 2nd fetches the key and stores in the directory you just created.
Then you add the repository (repo) details to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources using any editor.
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources

and copy and paste in the magic text:
Types: deb deb-src
URIs: https://qgis.org/debian
Suites: your-distributions-codename
Architectures: amd64
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/qgis-archive-keyring.gpg

Taking care to replace your-distributions-codename with your distributions name (e.g. jammy). If you don't know what your release is use lsb_release -cs to check.
Now you need to let apt know that there is a new repository:
sudo apt update

then you can install QGis in the same way as any other package.
sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass

This will install (and keep updating) the latest release, if you prefer the LTR version then use the URL https://qgis.org/debian-ltr in the line that starts URIs in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/qgis.sources.

i tried this again and it keeps telling im up to date while im not. if i come across grumpy, im sorry, i dont mean to.

What version do you have installed?
